# UITableView sectioned by letter like in contacts list

Tags: ios

I'm sure this question has been asked before, but I couldn't find anything in the search.

I have a list of city names which can change depending on the country selected. I would like to order these alpabetically and have them show up in sections based on the first letter (like the contacts list).

How can I accomplish this?? Do I have to manually create all the sections or is there a built-in way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sort your datasource to be in the order you wish, then reload the tableview.

Try making an NSDictionary of NSMutableArrays. Take the first letter of each city, toUpper it.  Then insert your city into the array for the letter k.

Number of sections = [[NSDictionary allKeys] count]

```
NSArray* cityNames = [NSArray arrayWithObject: @"Detroit"];

NSMutableDictionary* dataSource = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];    

for( NSString* city_name in cityNames){

    NSString* key = [[city_name substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString];

    if( ![dataSource objectForKey: key] ){
        [dataSource setObject:[NSMutableArray array] forKey:key];
    }
    [[dataSource objectForKey: key] addObject: city_name];
}
```

If you need more help setting up your datasource with your tableview say so in a comment and I'll help you more. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to manually create all sections. And it would be convenient to store sections in `NSDictionary`. To have lettered section indicies just return an array of them in `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:`